# EC Public Key Encryption with OpenSSL

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, public-key-encryption, public-key

Is there a possibility in PHP's OpenSSL implementation to encrypt via public key/decrypt via private key using PHP OpenSSL?

As per the [OpenSSL documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_SealInit.html), `openssl_seal()` does not support an EC public key.

> The public key must be RSA because it is the only OpenSSL public key
> algorithm that supports key transport.

`openssl_public_encrypt()` also throws an error when using it with an EC key.

My key creation works as follows:

```
// Configuration settings for the key
$config = array(
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_EC,
    "curve_name" => "secp521r1"
);
    
// Create the private and public key
$res = openssl_pkey_new($config);
    
// Extract the private key into $private_key
openssl_pkey_export($res, $private_key);
    
// Extract the public key into $public_key
$public_key = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
$public_key = $public_key["key"];
```

Is there any way to do ec public key encryption with OpenSSL?

Why is the failure of `openssl()` and `openssl_public_encrypt()` for EC not documented at [php.net](https://php.net)?

Comment: According to https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Elliptic_Curve_Operations there is an ECC encryption available: "The only Elliptic Curve algorithms that OpenSSL currently supports are Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman (ECDH) for key agreement and Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA) for signing/verifying."

Comment: The question was for encryption and not signing/verifying or key exchange.
So is there a PHP implementation for ECDH?

Comment: Encryption is not ECDH - ECDH is good for hybrid encryption (public + private keyexchange - this key is good for AES-encryption) but NO pure EC encryption.

Comment: I have found the php.net documentation to vary from ok to terrible, with most of it poor. I'm not sure what openssl supports, nor what the php bindings to openssl support, but Elliptic Curve El Gamal can be used for key transport. Much better is Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme (ECIES) which is almost certainly the right tool for your needs.